# Android build failed in jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, android-sdk-tools

I am building an android application in jenkins.
but it's saying 
The SDK directory ' /var/lib/jenkins/android-sdk' does not exist.

I have set the android sdk path 
[My andoid sdk configuration in jenkins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfcJd.png)

Kindly help me out. Thnaks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

**You can follow below steps to achieve this.**

> 1. Go to Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure System
> 2. Check "Environment variables"
> 3. add name: ANDROID_HOME, value -> your complete Android SDK dir path
> 4. click "add"
> 5. SCROLL DOWN CLICK SAVE

or

**I fixed it using:**

> 1. Copy your Android folder \Users{yourUser}\Library\Android\
> 2. Paste in the folder \Users\Shared\Jenkins\Library
> 3. Go to Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System
> 4. Check "Environment variables"
> 5. add name: ANDROID_HOME, value -> \Users\Shared\Jenkins\Library\Android\sdk
> 6. Add
> 7. Save

Comment: I have set the environment variable path for Android.But still it's giving the same issue :(